# Why can't I redirect to my failure page using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, newsletter, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am working on my newsletter project using Mailchimp API, it works but I can't redirect to a failure page if the status code is not 200, the browser says localhost refused to connect meanwhile success page redirection works great.
here's my code:

```
app.post("/", async(req, res, next)=>{
  const {fName, lName, email} = req.body.user;
  const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember("List_ID", {
    email_address: email,
    status: "subscribed",
    merge_fields:{
      FNAME: fName,
      LNAME: lName,
    },
  });
  if(res.statusCode === 200){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
  }
  else{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
  }

});
```

Comment: You probably want to check `response.statusCode`

Comment: got the same result.

Comment: I don't know if that's the reason here, but you always need to handle all failure paths. An `await` can throw, and in your case you would not handle that, due to that you then wouldn't send a response, and the request times out. You must wrap it in a `try catch` block. `try {  const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember("List_ID", ...); if(...){...}else{...} } catch { res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html"); }`

Comment: You check the status code of `res` but you want to check the status code of `response`.

Comment: The `says localhost refused to connect` indicates that you don't send a response. But @TheFool is also right. So you have two problems, you check the `statusCode` and the wrong response object, and you don't handle the error case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all using `async` with `express` is tricky, if anything in your `async` function throws express won't get notified about that which would result in an error like:

> localhost refused to connect

A quick and dirty solution would be to warp your whole body of the `async` function into a `try .. catch` block. But that's tedious and you might still miss some side conditions.

So instead you would want to create a wrapper for that which could look that way:
(There are probably better implementations for an express async wrapper)

```js
function asyncExpressWrapper(fn) {
   // return the wrapping middelware be used.
   return async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
         // call the actual middelware you passed
         await fn(req, res, next);
      } catch (err) {
         // will catch any error thrown in fn
         next(err)
      }
   }
}
```

And use it that way:

```js
app.post("/", asyncExpressWrapper(async(req, res, next) => {
  const {
    fName,
    lName,
    email
  } = req.body.user;

  const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember("List_ID", {
    email_address: email,
    status: "subscribed",
    merge_fields: {
      FNAME: fName,
      LNAME: lName,
    },
  });

  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
  } else {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
  }
}));
```

Now that will solve the `localhost refused to connect` problem, and express will tell you which error you didn't handle.

Besides that your `res.statusCode === 200` will check the express response statusCode which at that point is always true, if `response` has a `statusCode` it has to be `response.statusCode === 200`.

Now your `__dirname + "/failure.html"` likely still is not shown, as the Promise returned by `mailchimp.lists.addListMember` likely rejects in the error case. So you needd also a `try ... catch` in your middleware:

```js
app.post("/", asyncExpressWrapper(async(req, res, next) => {
  const {
    fName,
    lName,
    email
  } = req.body.user;
  
  try {
    const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember("List_ID", {
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: fName,
        LNAME: lName,
      },
    });

    // you probably don't need that if-else at all and only emit 
    // success here, but I don't know mailchimp.lists.addListMember 
    // so that's up to you to figure out. 
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
    } else {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
    }
  } catch(err) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
  }
}));
```

---

The Express documentation has a section about [Promises](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-promises) suggesting this as a wrapper:

```
const wrap = fn => (...args) => fn(...args).catch(args[2])
```

The one I suggested also works if you pass a none `async` function to it from which you accidentally don't return a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "try..catch" to catch unexpected error.
See below.

```
try {
   if(res.statusCode === 200){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
   }
   else{
     res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
   }
} catch (err) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
}
```

Comment: While I agree that a `try...catch` is missing (see my comment to the question), that `try..catch` block here shouldn't change anything. `sendFile` would only throw if no path is provided, the path is not a string, or it isn't absolute and the option is provided that it has to be absolute.